# write a SQL query to find the maximum salary with the given table

Tags: mysql

Write a query to find maximum salary from employee table w.r.t. dept name and gender. (Every dept has a male & a female record)

| dept.name | gender | salary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Finance | M | 4000 |
| Finance | F | 4500 |
| HR | M | 3000 |
| HR | F | 2000 |
| Accounts | M | 6000 |
| Accounts | F | 7000 |

Answer (score 0):

You could this:

Select max(salary), dept.name from the_table

Comment: When you use `max` function  you need to `group by`  when `sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

Answer (score 0):

You have some way of doing this:

If you want to use `max` function you have to `group by`, for example `dept_name` in your case. And you will find the max salary for the dept_name.

```
select max(salary) as max_salary ,
                        dept_name 
from employee  
group by dept_name 
order by max_salary DESC;
```

If you do not want to use `max` with `group by` , use `limit` like:

```
   select dept_name,
             gender,
             salary 
   from employee 
   order by salary desc limit 1;
```

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7yUJcuMJPncBBnrExKbzYz/88

Answer (score 0):

You may add the conditions, as follows:

```
SELECT MAX(salary) 
FROM employee 
WHERE gender= 'F'
AND dept.name='Accounts';
```